# Do Cloud Functions count as concurrent connections to Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

In my project I‘m using the realtime database as well as the Firestore database. My cloud functions triggers when a document is added to a specific collection inside my Firestore database. The function then writes to my realtime database to update some statistics. I noticed that even if no user is connected to my realtime database, the count of concurrent connections increases when the cloud function writes to the realtime database. Does this mean that my cloud functions count as concurrent connections and will decrease the amount of users that can connect to my realtime database at once as there is a limit of 100k concurrent connections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll incur one connection for each *server instance* running your functions.  It is not one per individual *function invocation*.  So, if it only requires one server instance to run your function, then it will only cost one connection.  When a server instance is automatically deallocated from your project, its connection will go away.

You will need an *extremely* busy set of functions in order to make a real dent in your 100K concurrent connection cap for Realtime Database.  I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what if the code in Cloud Functions is connecting back to the Firebase Database? And for that answer: does it make a difference if you use `event.data.ref`/`event.data.adminRef` or `admin.database().ref()`?

Comment: There is one more thing that‘s confusing me. In the documentation it says that there is a limit of 1,000 write operations/second. So if I create chat functionality, where every message sent will be written to the receiver and sender node. Does this mean that only 500 users can send a message at the same time even tough there would be 99,5K connections left?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'm going to hedge on that one because adminRef is eventually going to be deprecated (you should use the admin SDK directly in that case).  But today, in either case, the functionality is backed by the admin SDK.  So, whatever it does to handle both cases is what you can expect.  Perhaps that means different connections.

Comment: @Lukas123321 The answer to your question is dependent on your definition of "at the same time".  Bear in mind that timing is not the issue.  It's the amount of write contention.  All the writes will make it through - each may just have to wait to be fully synchronized.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thank you for answering my questions. But could the 1000 write operations/second limit be removed if necessary?

Comment: @Lukas123321 No, that's a real world limitation.  Writes can only happen so quickly.